# Draw Rectangle or Arrow in PictureBox()

Tags: c#, winforms

**This work correct. If I take picture from my system.**

```
        pictures[idObjekt] = new Bitmap(@"C:\rectangle.png");
        picBox[idObjekt] = new PictureBox();
        picBox[idObjekt].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 7);
        picBox[idObjekt].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        picBox[idObjekt].ClientSize = new Size(53, 40);
        picBox[idObjekt].Image = pictures[idObjekt];
        picBox[idObjekt].MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
        picBox[idObjekt].MouseMove += pictureBox1_MouseMove;
        picBox[idObjekt].PreviewKeyDown += Form1_PreviewKeyDown;
        picBox[idObjekt].Tag = idObjekt;
        this.Controls.Add(this.picBox[idObjekt]);
```

But when I try draw something in PictureBox() I see only empty PictureBox() I don't know why this does not work correct.

```
        pictures[idObjekt] = new Bitmap(1000, 1000, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        picBox[idObjekt] = new PictureBox();
        picBox[idObjekt].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 7);
        picBox[idObjekt].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        picBox[idObjekt].ClientSize = new Size(500, 500);
        picBox[idObjekt].MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
        picBox[idObjekt].MouseMove += pictureBox1_MouseMove;
        picBox[idObjekt].PreviewKeyDown += Form1_PreviewKeyDown;
        picBox[idObjekt].Tag = idObjekt;
        picBox[idObjekt].BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Controls.Add(this.picBox[idObjekt]);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictures[idObjekt]);

        // Rectangle
        int heightRec = 100;
        int widthRec = 250;
        int pozitionX = 10;
        int pozitionY = 10;

        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, pozitionX + 1, pozitionY + 1, widthRec - 3, heightRec - 3);
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, pozitionX + 2, pozitionY + 2, widthRec - 3, heightRec - 3);
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, pozitionX, pozitionY, widthRec, heightRec);
        g.DrawString("The Code Project", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic),
        SystemBrushes.WindowText, new PointF(10, 50));

        // Arrow
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 7);
        p.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;

        // Arrow
        Point point1 = new Point(100, 100);
        Point point2 = new Point(100, 100);
        g.DrawLine(p, point1, point2);
        g.Dispose();
        pictures[idObjekt].Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time around, you never assign the bitmap to the PictureBox.

```
picBox[idObjekt].Image = pictures[idObjekt];
```

And after you finish drawing, why do you call `pictures[idObjekt].Dispose()`?
If you need the image in the PictureBox to stay, you should not dispose the image.